# Drawer Not opens on Android

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

[image]

I'm using react-navigation and implementing drawer.
It worked on the iOS but it's not working on the android.

When I call _drawToggle,

```
  _drawerToggle = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen');
  }
```

The screen gets darker(seems like working, but not quite). 
Here is return value of the `render()` function.

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
   <Header
     headerText="Restaurant List"
     navigation={this.props.navigation}
     drawerToggle={this._drawerToggle}
   />
   <ScrollView>
     <FlatList
        data={restaurants}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
     />
   </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: Are you using a `custom drawer`, which does't inherit  `flex` or a predefined `width`? Try adding `drawerWidth` prop to the `navigator`.Otherwise you may need to post the working code on https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: DrawerWidth as a prop? Can we just use it on navigationOptions?

Comment: It didnt work though :(

Comment: `drawerWidth` is [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator.html#drawernavigatorconfig), either you may need to post a complete code (which replicates the issue) or make a snack snippet [here](snack.expo.io)